# How to parse a variable into firebase.database().ref().set({...})

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-ios

i am trying to add firebase into my react-native application, and have the following code:

```
_saveFile(fileName){
    var userPath = "/Users/Johnny/files/";
    var storageString = ("Johnny Johnson\n"+ date + "\n" + 
            this.state.text);
    var name = fileName;

    firebase.database().ref(userPath).set({
        name : storageString
    })

}
```

But as you can probably guess, this isn't getting the `name` variable and storing it as the key. It is simply storing it in the database as..

Users -> Johnny -> files -> {name: "whatever the string was i saved"}

and then simply overriding it every time i try and make a new file. Just wondering how i go about parsing in this fileName variable? It is getting the child value correctly - which is why i am confused.

Any help would be appreciated, i'm pretty new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put brackets around `name` it will use the `name` variable instead of creating a key called `name`.

```
firebase.database().ref(userPath).set({
    [name] : storageString
})
```

Comment: Thanks! any idea why this deleted my current entry in the database? ( its only storing one )

Comment: Not too familiar with firebase, when you're setting it's overwriting and only storing one? maybe you need to retrieve what's currently there and append it to the setting:
`const currentValues = //get what's currently stored at that filepath
firebase.database().ref(userPath).set({
    ...currentValues,
    [name] : storageString
});`